# Virtual Tour using sketch up, ajax, flash technologies

Tags: ajax, flash, actionscript-3, export, sketchup

I want to know if there are existing technology that make your 3d models in sketch into virtual tours, using either Ajax or Flash for web presentation.

If there's none, which will be a good approach in creating a virtual tour? Flash or Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already comfortable in flash, i would recommend [Papervision 3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) . If your're not already comfortable in flash, or silverlight, or Unity 3D i would recommend creating your virtual tour as a set of rendered videos.  It is going to take a lot of time and learning to create a virtual tour application in interactive 3D from scratch. That being said, any one of the above technologies is a good bet.

Comment: Yeah you have a point there, I think I would just have to convert it to videos. I also like the Unity 3D. Papervision 3d is awesome will try that in other projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flash's 3D capabilities are severely limited; You might get better results with Silverlight (by coding a reader for sketchup models to a 3D scene) or [Unity3D's plugin](http://unity3d.com/gallery/live-demos/index.html#tropical-paradise) (by exporting the model from sketchup and importing into their toolchain).